# How can I evaluate a column of numbers to find changes in a repeating sequence?

Tags: t-sql, numerical-analysis

I have a table of 100,000 rows and one column is a repeating series of numbers that represent a "spot" in a robot production line. I need to detect when the repeating sequence changes. A sequence consists of an even number and the odd numbers either side. Therefore the numbers in a given sequence are either 1 or 2 apart, e.g. 32, 31, 33, 31, 33, 31, 33, 32, 31, 32, 31, 33, 32. The order of the three numbers is random except a number cannot follow itself. The sequence can change, e.g. 33, 32, 31, 33, 31, 33, 31, 32, 31, 32, 33, 44, 45, 44, 43, 45, 43, 45, 43, 44, 29, 30, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 29, 31, 29, 30, . . .

I want to be able to detect every change in sequence and flag each change with 1 (leaving a default 0 in rows where there is no change).

Where  it is not certain if a number belongs to one sequence or another, e.g. 32, 31, 33, 33, 31, 30, 29, 30, 31 (the sequence has changed from one based around 32 to one based around 30) it is assumed the last number that can belong to either sequence belongs to the "lead-in" sequence.

Each step in the sequence of numbers has a unique moveID, partitioned by facility and robotNum.

I've tried using Lead and Lag to derive the numbers before and after a "spot", finding the difference between the sum of the three numbers before a spot and sum of the three numbers after a spot to see if the the difference exceeds certain limits thus indicating a change in sequence. (See following code).

```
SELECT moveID, facility, robotNum, spot, 
       CASE WHEN (((lastSpot1 + lastSpot2 + lastSpot3) - (nextSpot1 +  nextSpot2 +  nextSpot3))/3 BETWEEN -1.3 AND 1.3 ) 
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0 
       END 
       AS sequenceChange
     FROM
             ( SELECT facility, robotNum,
             , LEAD(spot,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY facility, robotNum ORDER BY facility, robotNum, moveID ) AS nextSpot1
             , LEAD(spot,2,0) OVER(PARTITION BY facility, robotNum ORDER BY facility, robotNum, moveID ) AS nextSpot2
             , LEAD(spot,3,0) OVER(PARTITION BY facility, robotNum ORDER BY facility, robotNum, moveID ) AS nextSpot3
             , LAG(spot,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY facility, robotNum ORDER BY facility, robotNum, moveID ) AS lastSpot1
             , LAG(spot,2,0) OVER(PARTITION BY facility, robotNum ORDER BY facility, robotNum, moveID ) AS lastSpot2
             , LAG(spot,3,0) OVER(PARTITION BY facility, robotNum ORDER BY facility, robotNum, moveID ) AS lastSpot3

            FROM SequenceTable1 
        ) t1
     ORDER BY facility, robotNum, moveID.
```

This method is unreliable, however, because the sum of the first 3 digits of some different sequences overlap. Some way is needed to "amplify" the difference so changes can be detected more reliably, and 1 updated in the "sequenceChange" column at the start of each new sequence.

Comment: SQL is not the best tool for this type of analytical functions. You need something like matlab or looker.

Comment: Does each sequence always start with its even number?   Although you've told us a lot, you still haven't given a completely clear description of the logic to be followed.

Comment: No, a sequence does not always start with its even number. I've found a possible solution and will post it soon.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of simple relationships between sequences of numbers described in the question. One is that the difference between numbers in a sequence is never more than 2. Another is that the even number in each unique sequence has a modulus of 2 and some have a modulus of 4. With the modulus, the even number that the odd numbers belong to can be easily found.  I identified all the possible logic combinations covering the differences between numbers to detect a change in sequence (there are 144 possible combinations covered by 20 rules) and also calculate the modulus. Following are the SQL case statements  for the rules that need to be applied sequentially.

```
                CASE    
                    WHEN    Spot = 1 OR Spot = 2   THEN 2   
                    WHEN    Spot = 3 and (POWER(lastSpot1,4) + POWER(Spot,4) + POWER(nextSpot2,4)) <114   THEN 2    
                    WHEN    Spot = 3 and nextSpot1 =  5   THEN 4    
                    WHEN    Spot = 3 and nextSpot1 = 4    THEN 4    
                    WHEN    Spot%4=0   THEN 4   
                    WHEN    Spot%4!=0 and Spot%2=0   THEN 2 
                    WHEN    Spot%2=1 and lastSpot1%2=1 AND (Spot -2 =lastSpot1 OR Spot+2 = lastSpot1) AND ((Spot+lastSpot1)/2)%4=0   THEN 4 
                    WHEN    Spot%2=1 and lastSpot1%2=1 AND (Spot -2 = lastSpot1 OR Spot+2 = lastSpot1) AND ((Spot+lastSpot1)/2)%4!=0 and ((Spot+lastSpot1)/2)%2=0   THEN 2  
                    WHEN    Spot%2=1 AND lastSpot1%2=0 AND (Spot-1 = lastSpot1 OR Spot+1 = lastSpot1) AND lastSpot1%4=0    THEN 4   
                    WHEN    Spot%2=1 AND lastSpot1%2=0 AND (Spot-1 = lastSpot1 OR Spot+1 = lastSpot1) AND lastSpot1%4!=0 AND lastSpot1%2=0     THEN 2   
                    WHEN    Spot%2=1 AND lastSpot1%2=1 AND (Spot-2 > lastSpot1 OR Spot+2 <  lastSpot1) AND nextSpot1%2=1 AND (Spot -2 = nextSpot1 OR Spot+2 = nextSpot1) AND  ((Spot+nextSpot1)/2)%4=0   THEN 4 
                    WHEN    Spot%2=1 AND lastSpot1%2=1 AND (Spot-2 > lastSpot1 OR Spot+2 <  lastSpot1) AND nextSpot1%2=1 AND (Spot -2 = nextSpot1 OR Spot+2 = nextSpot1) AND  ((Spot+nextSpot1)/2)%4!=0 AND and ((Spot+nextSpot1)/2)%2=0   THEN 2   
                    WHEN    Spot%2=1 AND lastSpot1%2=1 AND (Spot-2 > lastSpot1 OR Spot+2 <  lastSpot1) AND nextSpot1%2=0 AND (Spot - 1 = nextSpot1 OR Spot+1 = nextSpot1) AND  nextSpot1%4=0   THEN 4   
                    WHEN    Spot%2=1 AND lastSpot1%2=1 AND (Spot-2 > lastSpot1 OR Spot+2 <  lastSpot1) AND nextSpot1%2=1 AND (Spot -2 = nextSpot1 OR Spot+2 = nextSpot1) AND   nextSpot1%4!=0 AND and nextSpot1%2=0   THEN 2    
                    WHEN    Spot%2=1 AND lastSpot1%2=0 AND (Spot-1 > lastSpot1 OR Spot+1 <  lastSpot1) AND ((nextSpot1%2=1 AND (Spot-2 > nextSpot1 OR Spot+2 <  nextSpot1) ) OR(nextSpot1%2=0 AND (Spot-1 > nextSpot1 OR Spot+1 <  nextSpot1)))   THEN lastSpotStart    
                    WHEN    Spot%2=1 AND lastSpot1%2=1 AND (Spot-2 > lastSpot1 OR Spot+2 <  lastSpot1) AND ((nextSpot1%2=1 AND (Spot-2 > nextSpot1 OR Spot+2 <  nextSpot1) ) OR(nextSpot1%2=0 AND (Spot-1 > nextSpot1 OR Spot+1 <  nextSpot1)))   THEN lastSpotStart    
                    WHEN    Spot%2=1 AND lastSpot1%2=0 AND (Spot-12 > lastSpot1 OR Spot+1 <  lastSpot1) AND nextSpot1%2=0 AND (Spot - 1 = nextSpot1 OR Spot+1 = nextSpot1) AND  nextSpot1%4=0   THEN 4  
                    WHEN    Spot%2=1 AND lastSpot1%2=0 AND (Spot-1 > lastSpot1 OR Spot+1 <  lastSpot1) AND nextSpot1%2=0 AND (Spot - 1 = nextSpot1 OR Spot+1 = nextSpot1) AND   nextSpot1%4!=0 AND and nextSpot1%2=0   THEN 2   
                    WHEN    Spot%2=1 AND lastSpot1%2=0 AND (Spot-1 > lastSpot1 OR Spot+1 < lastSpot1) AND nextSpot1%2=1 AND  (Spot-2 = nextSpot1 OR Spot+2 = nextSpot1)  AND ((Spot + nextSpot1)/2)%4=0    THEN 4   
                    WHEN    Spot%2=1 AND lastSpot1%2=0 AND (Spot-1 > lastSpot1 OR Spot+1 < lastSpot1) AND nextSpot1%2=1 AND  (Spot-2 = nextSpot1 OR Spot+2 = nextSpot1)  AND lastSpot1%4!=0 AND  ((Spot + nextSpot1)/2)%2=0   THEN 2    
            ELSE 1      
            END AS seqMod
```

Next, to calculate the index for each number in each sequence (the index is the sequences' even number), I used the following code (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever):

```
            CASE 
            WHEN seqMod = 4 AND (Spot = 1 OR Spot = 2) THEN 2  -- for when a robot that started at index 4 returns to index 2
            ELSE 
            CONVERT(int, ROUND((Spot +  CASE    WHEN seqMod = 2 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END )/4.0,0)* 4 - CASE    WHEN seqMod = 2 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END   )
            END AS spotIndex
```

With the index it's easy to detect changes from one sequence to another